# Batch "Copy to My Calendar" VBA Macro for Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, appointment

I have approximately 14,000 Outlook invitations in a Outlook folder that was generated from a legal discovery.  Counsel would like all these imported into a normal "Calendar View" (turning the invite into an actual calendar entry).  The two solutions I came up with is either require forwarding the invitation to a separate account (and auto accept) or use the Outlook "Copy to My Calendar" option which is what I'm hoping to accomplish.

Copied below is code I found to FORWARD all selected invitations in the Outlook folder. My concern with the forward is that it will notify the meeting organizer which we certainly don't want. I'm hoping someone can suggested a modification so this triggers "Copy to My Calendar" instead.  Any help or guidance would greatly be appreciated!

```
Sub BatchForwardMultipleCalendarItems()
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objCalendarItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
 
    Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 
    For i = objSelection.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set objCalendarItem = objSelection.Item(i)
 
        Set objMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With objMail
            .Attachments.Add objCalendarItem
            'Change the recipient's email address
            .Recipients.Add ("shelly@datanumen.com")
            .Recipients.ResolveAll
            .Subject = objCalendarItem.Subject
            .Body = "Type body here ...."
            .Send
       End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new mail item in the code and just sending it out with an attached appointment item:

```
 Set objMail = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

You can use the [AppointmentItem.ForwardAsVcal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.forwardasvcal) method which forwards the `AppointmentItem` as a `vCal` (virtual calendar item). A `MailItem` object that represents the new mail item to which the calendar information is attached is returned back.

There is no other way available in the Outlook object model.